# How to preview captured video on a SurfaceView?

Tags: java, android, surfaceview, android-mediarecorder, surfaceholder

I have used this code to capture a video and preview it on surface. But there is some logical error. Camera does not capture video. i don;t understand what is the error

```
public class VideoCapture extends Activity implements    View.OnClickListener,SurfaceHolder.Callback          
{

    MediaRecorder recorder;
    SurfaceHolder holder;
    boolean recording = false;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        initRecorder();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_capture);

        SurfaceView cameraView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.CameraView);
        holder = cameraView.getHolder();
        holder.addCallback(this);
        holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        cameraView.setClickable(true);
        cameraView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void initRecorder() {
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
        recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);

        CamcorderProfile cpHigh = CamcorderProfile
                .get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
        recorder.setProfile(cpHigh);
        recorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/videocapture_example.mp4");
        recorder.setMaxDuration(50000); // 50 seconds
        recorder.setMaxFileSize(5000000); // Approximately 5 megabytes
    }

    private void prepareRecorder() {
        recorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());

        try {
            recorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            finish();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            finish();
        }
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (recording) {
            recorder.stop();
            recording = false;

            // Let's initRecorder so we can record again
            initRecorder();
            prepareRecorder();
        } else {
            recording = true;
            recorder.start();
        }
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        prepareRecorder();
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                               int height) {
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        if (recording) {
            recorder.stop();
            recording = false;
        }
        recorder.release();
        finish();
    }
}
```

The XML file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<SurfaceView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/CameraView"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Comment: Could you give more detail as to exactly what happens and what does not happen when you run this code?  Additionally, what sort of troubleshooting have you performed?

Comment: @Julie When i try to open it in mobile phone, black screen appears  but the video file is created of size 0B . I have permissions to access Camera still it does not work. I was not sure earlier if it was the camera that's not working or the surface but it turns out to be "Camera".

As for troubleshooting i checked whether the phone is blocking access to camera but that is not the case. This code was working pretty good earlier but out of nowhere it has stopped delivering.